# Is there a library that can get the ip addresses and ports from the winpcap raw data of a packet?

Tags: c++, winpcap

I am using WinPcap to capture packets from the network.
Using `pcap_next_ex()`  I get the raw packet as a `u_char*` (the length of the array is given in the packet metadata, the struct `pcap_pkthdr`).

How can I get the Ip and the port of the source and the destination of this packet?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know anything about PCAP but I would guess that the data is a [IP header](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_header_%28disambiguation%29) which is probably followed by either a [TCP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol) header or a [UDP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Datagram_Protocol) header.

Comment: The problem is that i do not know which protocol is used, and the packets i capture is in application level. I am looking for an existing DLL which solves the problem rather than implementing a solution...

Comment: @HadarGrubman You need to actually *look* at the data. An IP-header have specific fields with specific values at specific offsets, other (non-IP) protocols are similar. However, the likelihood that you will see anything else than an IP-packet will be infinitesimally small. By checking the IP-header you will know what kind of sub-protocol (TCP/UDP/other) is used, and that will tell you how to parse the rest of the data.